# Jquery PHP Dynamic SelectBox IE Bug

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I created two listboxes that are dynamically populated. The User selects an option in the first listbox and then the second listbox shows the options according the selection.

Everything works Ok on FireFox, Safari, Chrome but not on Internet Explorer (As Usual).

**Error:**
When you select an option on the first listbox the second listbox don't return anything and becomes empty.

I´ve made some tests and the php file is triggered by Internet Explorer (I can output the values) but the second listbox don't return these values.

Here's the HTML SelectBox

```
<select name="list01" id="list01"/>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select name="list02" id="list02"/>
    <option value="0">Select an Option First</option>
</select>
```

Here's the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#list01').change(function(){
        $('#list02').load('get_list.php?selected='+$('#list01').val() );
    });
});
```

And here the get_list.php

```
$id = $_GET['selected']; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ".$id." ORDER BY id ASC");

echo "<option value='*'>Select your Item</option>";     
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
```

As i said, everything works fine on FF, Chrome and Safari, but not on IE.

I'm missing something?

Comment: but the second listbox don't return these values. when?

Comment: When you select an item on the first SelectBox.

Comment: 2nd list box is not showing the options returned from php isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the code work on any browser but not on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#list01').change(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type:get,
            url:'get_list.php?selected='+$('#list01').val(),
            success:function(data) {

             $('#list02').html("");
             $('#list02').html(data);

            } 
        }) // end of ajax
    });
});
```

Comment: I get erro: get is not defined. I´m using Jquery 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I Just realized that the code work with IE on PHP 5.2 server but don´t work with IE on PHP 5.3 server. This don't make any sense to me but i'll try to find out why. If anyone could help me i'll be thankful.